# Testing socio-economic differences in an experiment

Tags: r, treatment-effect

I am just a beginner in statistics and currently i am doing a research.
I have conducted an experiment with a control group and a treatment group. Although  the difference overall is not significant I want to study whether there is a significant influence within various socio-economic groups.
E.g. I want to know if higher educated people are effected more by the treatment than younger and if this difference is significant.
I have 4 variables (age, income, education and gender). What statistical test could i use?

Comment: You are referring to testing interaction effects, i.e. testing whether the effect of one variable (treatment/control in your case) on the outcome varies by the level of another variable.  The most general way to test interactions is to construct a regression with interaction terms for the relationships you want to test.  You just have to pick the right type of regression depending on the nature of your dependent/outcome variable.

Comment: My dependent variable is a dummy variable (option A chosen = 1 if not = 0), so I will do a Binary logistic regression. If I am understanding correctly, to find the difference in treatment effect between e.g male and female, I could perform the following regression: 
Y = B0 + B1*(Treatment) + B2*(Female)+B3(Treatment*Female). 
is that right?

Comment: Right, that will work.